# Theorem about prime numbers which are one more than a multiple of $8$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Assume the following:
A prime $p>2$ can be written as $p=m^2+n^2$  for integral $m,n$ iff $p$ is $1$ more than a multiple of $4$.

Now, prove that every prime which is one more than a multiple of $8$ be written as $x^2+16y^2$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

I was able to show that if $p$ is one more than a multiple of $8$, it is one more than a multiple of $4$, and since $p$ is odd, one of $m$ or $n$ is odd. But I am unable to go beyond this point. Could someone please help?

Comment: Primes are odd, so $m$ and $n$ have to be one odd, one even at any rate, whether they are congruent to $1$ or $3$ modulo $4$.  Examine the problem by considering what the squares are modulo $8$.  What form must the even square take?

Comment: Even squares leave remainder 0 or 4 when divided by 8. The former happens when the non square number is a multiple of 4. How does this help me determine what form the even square must take?

Comment: See the answer for how that helps. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p\equiv 1\pmod{\! 8}$. Since $p\equiv 1\pmod{\! 4}$, exist $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ giving you $p=x^2+y^2$.

Exactly one of $x,y$ is even, wlog $y$ is even.

$x^2\equiv 1\pmod{\! 8}$, $y^2\equiv \{0,4\}\pmod{\! 8}$ and $p\equiv 1\pmod{\! 8}$.

So we must have $y^2\equiv 0\pmod{\! 8}$.

$8\mid y^2\iff 4\mid y$. Let $y=4m$. Then $p=x^2+16m^2$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to prove if 8 divides y^2, 4 divides y? I understand how to do it the other way.

Comment: @Av96 By contrapositive (or contradiction): if $4\nmid y$ (i.e. $2^2\nmid y$), then $y=2y_1$ with $y_1$ odd. But then $y^2=2^2y_1^2$ and $y_1^2$ is odd, so $2^3\nmid y^2$.